# How to get colored transient messages in QStatusBar?

Tags: qt, colors, message, qstatusbar

I need to color-code messages flashing in the status bar of my Qt5.5 app.

I am using showMessage like this:

```
ui->statusBar->showMessage("My Message", 5000);
```

I would like to change the color of a single message.
I've found no way short of subclassing QStatusBar and overriding showMessage().
Do I really need such an invasive change?

I tried to use Rich Text along the lines of:

```
ui->statusBar->showMessage(QString("<html><head/><body><p style=\"color:red\">%1</p></body></html>").arg("My Message"));
```

but it doesn't seem to be recognized (prints the tags).

Altering the palette or setting the style-sheet will not be limited to the current message.

What else could I try?

Comment: I believe that there is same problem but unfortunately still not resolved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795214/qt-statusbar-color#5795696
(https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11)

Answer (score 6):

How to get colored transient messages in QStatusBar?

> Altering the palette or setting the style-sheet will not be limited to the current
>   message.

Altering the stylesheet does not necessarily apply to all widgets in the program. You can definitely limit the scope of the stylesheet.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // the stylesheet can be applied within ui->statusBar hierarchy of 
    // objects, but you can make it even more narrow scope as
    // ui->statusBar->setStyleSheet("QStatusBar{color:red}") if needed
    ui->statusBar->setStyleSheet("color: red");
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Text!");

    QTimer::singleShot(2000, this, SLOT(tryAnotherColor()));
}

void MainWindow::tryAnotherColor()
{
    ui->statusBar->setStyleSheet("color: blue");
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("More Text!");
}
```

> I tried to use Rich Text

My guess is that not all Qt widget controls have rich-text rendering functionality but most do understand CSS-like stylesheets..